# Change javascript from src before it is outputted?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to change the javascript from `<script src="http://example.com/" type="text/javascript"></script>` before it is outputted onto the page? The outputted data is in the format `document.write('<li><a href="http://example.com/reply/1">UsersName: This is the users message.</a></li>');`

I'd like to change it so the HTML on the page is `<li><a href="http://example.com/reply/1">UsersName</a><div id=message">This is the users message.</div></li>`

Comment: No, that is not possible but you could change the generated markup later using jQuery - can you use jQuery? Are you sure the google-chrome-extension tag is correct?

Comment: Ahh yes, forgot to mention this is for a Google Chrome extension. And yes you can use jQuery. How can i do this in jQuery. (I have little experience with jQuery)

Comment: You would need to either edit the JS or add JS to process after the initial JS has been processed... are either of these possible?

Comment: @dskvr No i cannot edit the original JS but i can add more JS after the first one has been processed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: this isn't the best idea, but it's all I can come up with..

In `<head>`, you could override `document.write` briefly, manipulate the data, then output it.

E.g.:

```
(function (write) {
    document.write = function (data) {
        // manipulate data here
        data = data.toLowerCase();

        // output manipulated data
        write(data);

        // set document.write back to normal
        document.write = write;
    };
}(document.write));
```

Comment: I will try that and get back to you. Genius idea, I never would have thought of that.

Comment: the setting document.write back to normal could just be `document.write = write;` I believe

Comment: @Seldaek - thanks, edited. I had that originally but was getting an `illegal invocation` error.. but not anymore.

Comment: Hmm, how i can change the location of the text though?

Comment: @user556396 - instead of just manipulating/outputting the text, you could store the data into a variable, wait for domReady, then have jQuery place it where you want it.

Comment: But I would not be able to seperate the username and the message into different variables, would I?

Comment: @user556396 - some regex would do the trick.. e.g. `data.match(/<li>[^>]+>([^:]+):\s*([^<]+)/)`

Comment: Ok so I would store `data = document.write` and then `username = data.match(/<li>[^>]+>([^:]+):\s*([^<]+)/)` and put username wherever i wanted? My Javascript is not very good as I'm sure you have noticed.       Edit: there are multiple `document.write` so i would i need to store `data = document.write[0]`

Comment: Well, when you override `document.write` as above, `data` is passed to your function. If you do.. `matches = data.match(...)`, you could set `username = matches[1]` and `message = matches[2]`. See [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) for more info